# Pra que servem índices no SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, índices

Para que serve o índice, eu sei que ele melhora a performance, mas o que o banco de dados faz por trás que melhora esta performance.
Quando é recomendado utilizar? E onde devo usar um índice?

Comment: Lembrando que índices não são algo próprio do SQLServer. Todos os bancos de dados relacionais possuem índices.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Imagine que o banco de dados é um carteiro que acaba de chegar em uma cidade que lhe é desconhecida, e que os dados são os destinatários das cartas que ele tem que entregar. Um índice mais simples seria como o sistema de códigos postais (no Brasil, CEP) enquanto índices mais robustos seriam como endereços completos. Ao contrário do carteiro da vida real, nosso carteiro SQL Server pode encontrar seu alvo sem o endereço - ele só vai precisar de mais tempo, porque nesse caso ele vai verificar todas as residências uma por uma.

**Resposta mais elaborada:**

Cada registro em um sistema de banco de dados tem um endereço no armazenamento (disco rígido ou SSD que seja).

Quando você faz uma pesquisa no banco que tem condições de pesquisa (`WHERE`), por padrão o SQL Server vai levantar todos os registros para a memória. Daí ele analisa um por um, checando contra as condições da pesquisa, para decidir se o registro faz parte do resultado ou não.

Como uma tabela pode ser de um tamanho várias vezes maior do que a memória RAM disponível, isso pode provocar muita lentidão.

Eis que surge a técnica da indexação. Basicamente, você elege uma ou mais colunas para serem índices. Daí, duas coisas podem/vão acontecer:

- A tabela será reordenada por aquelas colunas. Em caso de colunas de tipo textual, a ordenação é alfabética;
- Haverá uma cópia dessas colunas em um espaço especial do armazenamento. Essa cópia não precisa ser completa - pode ter apenas alguns registros estatisticamente relevantes. Dependendo da intensidade do uso, essa cópia pode ficar armazenada em cache na RAM. Cada registro de índice também contem um apontador, que diz o endereço do registro original no disco ou SSD.

Imagine que você tem uma tabela com um milhão de registros, com uma chave primária que é inteiro e auto-incremental. O índice poderia ficar na memória RAM e conter o ID e endereço de um a cada 100 registros. Agora vamos fazer uma consulta com algo do tipo `WHERE ID = X`, para um X qualquer.

Se você fizer a consulta sem ID indexado, você vai trazer até um milhão de registros para a memória e verificar de um por um qual tem o ID desejado.

Se você fizer a consulta com ID indexado, o banco vai ler o índice primeiro. Duas coisas podem acontecer:

- O banco encontra o ID X direto no índice. Com isso ele tem o endereço do registro no disco/SSD, e vai direto até ele sem nenhuma perda de tempo.
- O banco não encontra o ID no índice. Nesse caso, ele se dirige ao ID mais próximo no armazenamento e navega para frente ou para trás (conforme o caso) até encontrar o seu registro. Essa parte da busca parece com a busca normal que o banco faria sem o índice, mas como o banco já sabe o endereço aproximado a busca fica muito mais rápida.

Quanta velocidade você ganha com isso depende, varia de caso a caso. Para um banco de projeto escolar com tabelas com poucos registros, pode não fazer muita diferença. Mas para grandes bases com massas enormes de dados (listas telefônicas, por exemplo), a diferença é absurda. Não sei dizer um número preciso, mas nas maiores bases com as quais trabalhei, os índices baixavam o tempo de consulta de horas para milisegundos.

**Mais uma edição importante:** [tem uma pergunta no Stack Overflow sobre o quanto a memória RAM é mais rápida que um disco rídigo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371400/how-much-faster-is-the-memory-usually-than-the-disk). Isso é relevante porque **os índices mais acessados são mantidos na memória RAM**. A pergunta é de 2009, mas de lá pra cá a grandeza das disparidades de velocidade não mudou muito. Para pesquisas aleatórias, a memória RAM é algo entre cem mil a um milhão de vezes mais rápida que um disco rígido. Eis aí a principal vantagem do índice.

Answer (score 0):

Os índices (indexes) são estruturas em disco associadas a tabelas ou views, que agilizam o processo de recuperação das linhas de uma tabela ou de uma view. Estes índices podem conter chaves de uma ou mais colunas da tabela ou mesmo de uma view. Estas chaves, por conseguinte, são armazenadas na estrutura do SQL Server chamada de B-tree, que habilita o SQL Server a encontrar a(s) linha(s) associadas aos valores da chave de forma rápida e eficaz.

Leia mais em: SQL Server Cluster: Índices Clusterizados e não clusterizados http://www.devmedia.com.br/indices-clusterizados-e-nao-clusterizados-no-sql-server/30288#ixzz39XFTkuzg

Answer (score 0):

São elementos que utilizamos para indexar nossos dados, ou seja, definir uma "posição" ele dentro de um contexto. Muito parecido com um vetor ou array. Com os dados indexados as buscas ficam mais rápidas já que se sabe sua posição. O grande problema dos índices está na inserção, pois os dados indexados precisam estar ordenados para que aja uma melhor desempenho durantes as consultas, e para permanecerem ordenados precisar ser inseridos na posição correta!

Procure um pouco sobre estruturas de dados, podem ajudar!