# Quais as vantagens e desvantagens do uso de índices em base de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, índices

Quais as vantagens e desvantagens do uso de índices em base de dados?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: Relacionado: [Quando e em quais colunas deve-se usar índices?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76131/18246)

Answer (score 50):

## Vantagens

- [Melhora a performance](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32072/101) de consulta em muitos casos

  Os acessos aos dados são enormemente reduzidos. A forma como o índice é montado permite busca em uma parte dos dados. O mais comum é a utilização de [árvore binária](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220409/101) mantendo os dados ordenados ([mas existem outros tipos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101065/101)), assim uma busca binária pode ocorrer com complexidade O(log n), ou seja, você consegue achar uma informação disponível em índice em escala maior com o aumento de dados. Exemplo: Se tiver 50 linhas você consegue chegar onde quer em até 7 passos, sem o índice demoraria até 50. Com mais de um bilhão de linhas, você alcança o que deseja usando índice em pouco mais de 30 passos. A diferença é brutal.
- Pode trazer dados específicos de forma mais rápida

  Se o que você está pedindo para trazer (*fetch*) está todo em índice é possível que só uma consulta ao índice seja suficiente para obter os dados, sem precisar consultar a tabela de dados. E como os índices são menores e utilizados com mais frequência tendem a ficar em memória. Isto pode ser uma enorme vantagem.
- Permite o acesso de dados ordenados sem o custo de realizar a ordenação quando é necessário

  Até para obter a performance indicada no primeiro item os dados são naturalmente ordenados e isto é muitas vezes o que se deseja. Quando se sabe que vai utilizar muitas vezes o acesso sequencial de dados em determinada ordem, o índice vai ajudar muito. Caso contrário, uma tabela temporária (tem formas de otimizar isto, mas só para ajudar um pouco) deverá ser criada e todo o processo de ordenação deverá ser feito na hora. E ele é bem custoso.
- É fácil garantir que determinadas informações chaves não estejam duplicadas

  Como a busca é rápida e simples, descobrir se uma chave já existe é uma operação muito barata, pelo menos em comparação a descobrir o mesmo sem índice.

Dá para notar que a grande vantagem mesmo é o primeiro item, os demais são colaterais, embora de grande importância também.

## Desvantagens

- Piora a performance em escritas de dados no banco de dados

  Toda vez que uma informação chave for modificada (inserida, alterada, deletada) obrigará a escrita no índice. E o índice pode ser interpretado como uma tabela adicional escondida no banco de dados. E se a informação modificada está presente em várias chaves (vários índices), todos eles deverão ser alterados (em inclusão e remoção, todos sempre são afetados, ainda que seja possível otimizar para a remoção, sob pena de encarecer o custo de leitura). A alteração do índice implica em acesso de leitura e escrita nele, apesar de ser uma operação eficiente se comparada com o acesso direto à tabela, não deixa de ter um custo **adicional**.
- Aumenta o consumo de espaço para armazenamento do banco de dados (memória e disco)

  É claro que esta tabela adicional de chaves de índice vai ocupar um espaço extra também. Costuma ser um espaço menor que a tabela de dados original mas existe um custo extra. Se houver muitos índices é possível que o espaço seja até maior que a tabela original. Com muito índice fica difícil colocar tudo na memória.
- Aumenta a necessidade de manutenção interna no banco de dados

  Isto é um pouco dependente da implementação mas é comum que páginas de chaves sejam abandonadas conforme elas vão sendo alteradas. Além disto o DBA pode ter mais elementos com que se preocupar.
- Pode diminuir a performance de consultas

  [Não há garantias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32072/101) que todas as consultas serão mais rápidas com o uso de índices. Como há uma operação adicional para acesso ao índice antes do acesso ao dados principal é possível que a soma do tempo gasto nas operações seja maior que o acesso só ao dado principal mesmo que o acesso no principal sem índice seja teoricamente menos eficiente. Isto é mais comum quando o volume de dados é pequeno mas isto também é verdade em casos de consultas complexas ou onde uma grande porção dos dados da tabela serão retornados em qualquer ordem.

É virtualmente impossível criar índices para qualquer chave a não ser em tabelas extremamente simples. Então é ilusão achar que índices resolverão todos os problemas. E mesmo que fosse possível, eles causariam mais mal do que bem. Você só deve criar índices quando eles realmente são [necessários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23360/101) e fique provado que eles estão ajudando.

## Dicas para escolher o que indexar

- Evite criar muitos índices se há muita escrita nas tabelas envolvidas, índice ajuda muito a dar performance para leitura, mas prejudica a escrita.
- Sempre análise o padrão de uso para escolher o melhor tipo de índice. SGDBs modernos permitem índices que ajudam certos tipos de acesso OLTP ou OLAP.
- Chaves menores sem repetições e não nulas costumam ser melhores escolhas. Para os casos onde isto não é possível veja se o DBMS permite filtrar ser chaves.
- Quando usar mais de uma coluna escolher a ordem pode ajudar muito nos resultados de mais de uma consulta.
- Meça antes de criar um índice e evite-os em tabelas pequenas demais.
- O índice primário deve ser preferencialmente sequencial e imutável, além da obviedade de ser chave única.

É bom ressaltar que existem diversos tipos de índices. O mais comum é a árvore binária nas suas diversas variações, cada uma com uma situação mais adequada. Mas outros índices podem ser bem úteis também, como o *hash* onde a chave é determinada por uma fórmula e o acesso é feito direto por um índice posicional (mais comum em memória) ou índices invertidos muito utilizados para indexar textos onde as palavras contidas no texto são usadas como chaves e não dados inteiros como é comum em outros índices.

Para saber mais sobre o funcionamento do índice veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27877/101).

[Agora tem uma mais completa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183305/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou bastante!

Answer (score 6):

Basicamente, a vantagem é uma maior velocidade para acessar os dados, e a desvantagem é um desempenho menor para realizar inserções e alterações no banco.