# Como fazer consulta em MySQL com duas condições diferentes no WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, condição

Tenho duas consultas que funcionam perfeitamente separadas, mas precisava de todos os registros delas juntas.

Seriam essas:

```
SELECT b.idBanca AS idB, b.DataHora AS dataHora, 
       b.Sala AS sala, t.idTrabalho AS idT, 
       p.Nome AS orientador, a.Nome AS aluno, t.Nome AS trabalho 
FROM Bancas b 
INNER JOIN Trabalhos t ON t.idTrabalho = b.idTrabalho 
INNER JOIN Professores p ON t.idProfessor = p.idProfessor 
INNER JOIN Alunos a ON t.idAluno = a.idAluno 
INNER JOIN ProfessoresBancas pb ON b.idBanca = pb.idBanca 
WHERE t.idSemestre = '$idSemestre' AND pb.idProfessor = '$idProfessor' 
ORDER BY dataHora
```

e

```
SELECT b.idBanca AS idB, b.DataHora AS dataHora, 
       b.Sala AS sala, t.idTrabalho AS idT, 
       p.Nome AS orientador, a.Nome AS aluno, t.Nome AS trabalho 
FROM Bancas b 
INNER JOIN Trabalhos t ON t.idTrabalho = b.idTrabalho 
INNER JOIN Professores p ON t.idProfessor = p.idProfessor 
INNER JOIN Alunos a ON t.idAluno = a.idAluno 
INNER JOIN ProfessoresBancas pb ON b.idBanca = pb.idBanca 
WHERE t.idSemestre = '$idSemestre' AND p.idProfessor = '$idProfessor' 
ORDER BY dataHora
```

Só o que muda é o `$idProfessor` da clausula WHERE... Preciso dos registros das duas dentro do mesmo array chegando no PHP... Tentei com UNION, com SELECT encadeado e nada... Alguém saberia alguma alternativa?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eu não conferi toda a *query* mas se é o que você está dizendo acho que isto resolve:

```
SELECT b.idBanca AS idB, b.DataHora AS dataHora, 
       b.Sala AS sala, t.idTrabalho AS idT, 
       p.Nome AS orientador, a.Nome AS aluno, t.Nome AS trabalho 
FROM Bancas b 
INNER JOIN Trabalhos t ON t.idTrabalho = b.idTrabalho 
INNER JOIN Professores p ON t.idProfessor = p.idProfessor 
INNER JOIN Alunos a ON t.idAluno = a.idAluno 
INNER JOIN ProfessoresBancas pb ON b.idBanca = pb.idBanca 
WHERE t.idSemestre = '$idSemestre' AND 
       (p.idProfessor = '$idProfessor' OR pb.idProfessor = '$idProfessor')
ORDER BY dataHora
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/Select.php).

Você teve uma ideia interessante ao usar o `UNION`. De fato o que você precisa é fazer uma união mas existem diversas formas de fazer isto. Isto é possível fazer através de [operadores lógicos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective). Um `OR` é uma união, assim como o `AND` que você usou é uma intersecção.

Um `AND` deve satisfazer todas as condições estabelecidas então `t.idSemestre = '$idSemestre' AND pb.idProfessor = '$idProfessor'` precisa achar tanto o semestre procurado na tabela `t` como o o professor na tabela `pb` também.

Se na verdade você pode ter um professor adequado para a condição em duas tabelas diferentes você pode olhar nas duas, como você fez e **unir** estas duas buscas no `WHERE` com o `OR`.

Note que primeiro você olha uma tabela para achar se o semestre atende a necessidade e só depois ele vai olhar o professor em **qualquer** das duas tabelas. Para garantir que estas duas buscas pelo professor sejam uma só expressão é usado os parênteses.

O ideal realmente é que a procura pelo semestre venha antes porque se o banco de dados não achar nada ele nem tenta achar o professor nas duas tabelas. Afinal em um `AND` se você tem o primeiro operando falso, não adianta mais olhar o segundo, toda a expressão já será falsa.

No `OR` ocorre o oposto. Se você achar um professor na primeira sub-expressão (primeiro operando) do `OR` ele nem precisa olhar mais para o segundo operando porque já é certa que a expressão será verdadeira.

Lembre-se que o `WHERE` será aplicado à todas as linhas obtidas pelas demais cláusulas do `SELECT`. Por isto um [índice adequado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/35096/101) pode ser útil para agilizar a seleção.

Answer (score 6):

A sintaxe geral do WHERE é:

`WHERE <condição1> AND/OR <condição2> AND/OR <condição3> ...`

```
WHERE condição1 OR condição2
```

Se a *condição1* **OU** a *condição2* for verdadeira será realizada a consulta. 
O termo **OR** significa **OU**.

Observe que você pode estar combinando o uso do **AND** e do **OR**. Por exemplo:

```
WHERE (condição1 AND condição2) OR condição3
```

Nesse caso a *condição1* e a *condição2* precisa ser verdadeira para realizar a consulta **ou somente** a *condição3* para satisfazer a condição. Já nesse outro exemplo:

```
WHERE condição1 AND (condição2 OR condição3)
```

Observe que **os parênteses podem afetar a sua condição**, nesse caso a *condição1* precisa ser verdadeira **e somente uma das outras duas condições** serem verdadeiras (*condição2* ou *condição3*)

Agora só resta adaptar na sua *query*, de acordo com as suas necessidades.

Comment: Muito interessante.

Comment: E ainda há muitas técnicas que abrangem a programação, principalmente a forma de interpretação de cada linguagem, a maioria padroniza os mesmos conceitos e princípios lógicos.

Answer (score 0):

O UNION era para resolver sua necessidade, bastaria remover o order by do primeiro SQL e colocar o UNION entre eles mas, não seria o mais correto afinal as querys são identicas a unica diferença é o seu id do professor o que acaba em código duplicado sem necessidade.
experimente utilizar

```
WHERE t.idSemestre = '$idSemestre' AND
 (p.idProfessor in ('$idProfessor1','$idProfessor2',....,'$idProfessorN'))
```

Em questão de performance, procure fugir de OR/NOT pois o banco em muitas vezes pode acabar fazendo um table scan desnecessário.

Espero ter ajudado.