# Indexação de Banco de dados

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Qual a vantagem de se manter uma banco de dados indexado, com foreign key e indexação dos campos mais utilizados como em buscas?

Comment: Relacionado praticamente duplicata (não é porque tem duas perguntas em uma): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35088/101 Votei para fechar como ampla (se fosse uma seria duplicata, esse é o problema de pergunta ampla).

Comment: Relacionado: [Quando e em quais colunas deve-se usar índices?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76131/18246)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A diferença pode ser analisada utilizando o [explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html).

experimenta fazer um query sobre uma tabela, utilizando no where um campo. Depois experimenta colocar um index nesse campo e retirar, e ver as diferenças. O explain dá uma explicação daquilo que o MySQL faz quando executa um query.

Com o index as pesquisas são aceleradas, o que só tem impacto significativo a partir do momento em que essas tabelas começam a ter muitos registos. As foreign keys têm o mesmo impacto, e também ajudam na performance quando se faz um join entre várias tabelas.

Para além disso, as [foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) permitem definir o que deve acontecer quando se apagam registos de uma dada tabela, e o seu indice é referenciado noutras. Permite por exemplo apagar permissões de um dado utilizador se as permissões tiverem uma foreign key para o utilizador, e a linha correspondente do utilizador for apagada.