# O que são os índices, B-tree, hash, GiST e GIN?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, terminologia, índices

No [manual do PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html) tem o seguinte trecho :

> PostgreSQL provides the index methods B-tree, hash, GiST, and GIN.
>   PostgreSQL fornece os métodos de índice B-tree, hash, GiST e GIN.

Mas afinal o que são estes métodos? e qual suas diferenças?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## B-Tree

O [B-tree](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_B), ou alguma variação dele, é o mais comum em todos os sistemas de banco de dados. Ele é muito eficiente para quase todos os casos comuns de uso. É uma [árvore balanceada](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_bin%C3%A1ria) que permite todos os tipos de acesso (leitura, inserção remoção, em qualquer lugar) em tempo O(log n) (é um pouco mais complicado que isso, mas assim dá um ideia), que é muito rápido sempre, com volume muito grande ou muito pequeno de dados, mas importa mesmo quando é grande. É razoavelmente eficiente em espaço e mantém os dados ordenados, permitindo a leitura sequencial e de faixas eficientemente.

## Hash

Nos casos onde não precisa da ordem ou da busca sequencial e as chaves são únicas (em que o programador garante isto, o índice não consegue), evitam colisão e possui grande volume de dados, o índice pode ser mais eficiente se usar uma [função de cálculo de *hash*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_hash). Elas têm tempo O(1). Mas isso não quer dizer claramente mais rapidez. O tempo de cálculo da função pode ser maior que algumas iterações em uma árvore binária (e costumam haver poucas). Não costuma funcionar bem em disco ou outro armazenamento secundário.

A [estrutura de *hash*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabela_de_dispers%C3%A3o) ainda pode ter algumas dificuldades quando há colisões e buscas lineares (O(n)) são necessárias (ainda que raras, a não ser que as chaves não sejam únicas). Mas também pode-se "reclamar" de perda de tempo extra no B-tree quando necessita um rebalanceamento embora isto ocorra em circunstâncias mais específicas. Em todos os casos depende do algoritmo usado e o padrão de dados.

Existem casos, mas é raro, ter ganho expressivo por sua utilização. Pode haver ganhos em certos tipos de `JOIN` muito complexos. Só testando para ter certeza se vale a pena.

Ele não é *crash-safe*, nem é replicado, o que inviabiliza mais casos.

## GIN

O [GIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gin.html) (Generalized Inverted Index) permite que uma chave possua vários valores, ou seja, que aponte para várias linhas na tabela de dados. Isto é importante quando a mesma chave pode estar presente em vários itens de dados. Em alguns casos ter um índice assim (B-tree permite isto também) pode ser mais eficiente em espaço e tempo de acesso. Não espere ganhos miraculosos.

Um bom uso é para busca de textos livres (indicar onde determinas palavras estão presentes.

Outro uso é quando um tipo de dados específico criado pelo usuário (programador) no banco tem uma característica de multiplicidade.

De uma certa forma podemos considerar um índice mais baixo nível. Algo quase interno.

## GiST

O [GiST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gist.html) (Generalized Search Tree) é uma forma mais abstrata, mais interna, onde podem ser implementadas várias metodologias de acesso. Ela é uma árvore balanceada, mas não possui muitas regras. Estas devem ser especificadas em um nível mais alto, provavelmente para algum tipo específico criado pelo usuário.

## Conclusão

Em resumo, se não tiver um motivo muito forte, fique com o índice tradicional.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O que seria *crash-safe*?

Comment: Se parar no meio não dá problema.