# Sobre Trigger no postgres

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, oracle

Bom galera, meu problema é o seguinte, eu quero fazer um particionamento de tabela no postgres pois uma tabela tem zilhões de registros e a buscar nela demora muito (essa tabela tende a crescer consideravelmente nos próximos meses) e uma solução que eu encontrei foi fazer o particionamento de tabelas (Se alguém tiver outra solução) usando trigger só que até ai tudo bem, mas na hora que eu eu insiro um dado na minha tabela ele chama o gatinho, consigo pegar essas informações só que todos os dados vem como inteiro. Uns campos eu conseguir converter para text, mas outros como a data ele não converte nem para data e nem para string, a pergunta é como faço para deixar ele com seus tipos de dados padrões? Se não tiver como faço para deixa esse campo data com o tipo de date.

Comment: Raramente o particionamento é a solução, está demorando tem alguma outra coisa errada. Os índices tornam o acesso quase igual independente do tamanho da tabela. Mesmo que insista nesse erro, *trigger* provavelmente o pior recurso para se fazer isto. O resto parece confuso demais, e provavelmente desnecessário. Veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35088/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101065/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32052/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23348/101, http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: O banco já tem quase 1 Tera de dados, só essa tabela tá com 4 gigas e a tendência dela é dobra nós próximos meses. Os índices ajudam, mas com o tempo ela vai ficando mais lenta. Se caso tiver outra solução.

Comment: Eu acho que você está enganado. Minha experiência e das outras pessoas é outra. E os dados de como eles funcionam mostram isto. Quando a tabela dobra de tamanho (não importa o tamanho) quando se usa índice é como se adicionasse uma única linha nova para pesquisar o que deseja. è tão ínfimo que mal dá para medir. Se fizer o que está pretendendo tornará todas gravações mais caras, o que em grande volume pode ser trágico. Reafirmo que se está tendo problemas de performance com índice é porque está fazendo algo errado.

Comment: Não importa a quantidades de linhas que eu tenha em uma tabela, os índices sempre vão melhorar, pois essa tabela tem mais 500 milhões de registros. O que vc sugere para eu melhorar, essa tabela já tem indices que no começo foi bom, mais agora nao ta adiantando muito.

Comment: Seria bom por a estrutura das tabelas na pergunta. Grande chance de ser problema de modelagem. Quanto ao particionamento com trigger, acho mau uso dos dois recursos (do trigger, e do particionamento).

Comment: @JohnatanDantas, porque vc não cria um clone da mesma tabela( digo chamar o create table sem as constraints e indices ) e faz insert select só dos dados que vc quer ou varre uma certa quantidade de dados utilizando o limit?

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, combinando o recurso de herança, trigger e check, vc consegue particionar a tabela criando automaticamente uma nova tabela sem necessidade de fazer manual. A tabela particionada tamvem tera indices e isto tambem ajudara no desempenho. O particionamento é indicado para tabelas que possuem grandes volumes carregados em poucas vezes. Se for os falar em linhas, seria umas 50 milhoes de linhas por tabela , no minimo. 
A sua modelagem tamvem precisa ser revista e se estiver usando hibernate, tera dificuldadesno insert pois ele nao identificara o registro inserido.

Para particionar, primeiro identifique o melhor criterio (o ano, o id do cliente, etc). Depois crie um script para criar as tabelas com o comando inherits. Assim a tabela filha herdara todas as colunas da tabela pai e ainda as alteracoes posteriores que houver.
crie um check() na tabela filha indicando o criterio de insercao/particionamento (ex. Ano).
Todas as consultas sql tera de conter o campo chave checado(ano) , do contrario nao havera melhoria de performance.

Comment: eu fiz um script para criar o particionamento de tabelas usando herança, o particionamento ficou legal e criei check no id do cliente. Queria ver se da certo pois não queria mexer na aplicação, delegar essa responsabilidade para o banco. Eu utilizo hibernate, será que dará problemas como vc falou? Se caso não de para fazer vai ser o jeito delegar essa responsabilidade para o java.