# Selecionar linhas randomicamente

Tags: mysql, query, random

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema bem complexo mesmo, onde, em alguns casos preciso selecionar apenas alguns campos, um amigo que possui mais tempo de experiência na área me deu algumas dicas, porém ele não explicou o porquê.

Tenho a seguinte *query* que busca todos os usuários em ordem aleatória, mas nunca posso selecionar o mesmo usuário, está aqui a minha *query*:

`SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Então meu amigo critica dizendo:

> "vc usa RAND(), isso faz uma varredura na tabela inteira pra te retornar um usuário só"

O que ele quis dizer com isso?

O mesmo também diz:

> "e nunca use um SELECT *"

Por que?

Logo em seguida ele diz também que:

> "e provavelmente você não usa índices",
>
> "provavelmente você não otimiza o my.cnf"

O que ele quis dizer? Perguntei e ele apenas ignorou, fiz buscas na internet mas não encontrei nada a respeito.

Comment: Esse cara nao parece ser seu amigo...

Comment: Pior que é porém ele disse que tenho que aprender, então tenho quase certeza que ele me deu informações "quase incorretas" só pra eu virar mais uma madrugada pesquisando.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Complexidade sem explicação é subjetivo. Sem contexto a informação não tem valor.

Tempo de experiência não significa qualidade.

"Faça isto" sem explicação serve para nada.

> "vc usa RAND(), isso faz uma varredura na tabela inteira pra te retornar um usuário só"

Ele está correto, significa que a performance vai sofrer, fará uma leitura em toda tabela pegando todas as linhas existentes nela e aí uma delas será selecionada para te entregar. As pessoas acham que irá ler apenas uma linha, mas isso é um erro.

Provavelmente a solução na aplicação é mais adequada. Mas aí é um problema específico que não é o foco da pergunta.

> "e nunca use um SELECT *"

[Mito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21583/101).

> "e provavelmente você não usa índices",

Índices são fundamentais para dar performance. Se criado corretamente, claro.

É igual a um índice remissivo de um livro, se você precisa achar uma palavra importante no livro você tem duas opções: procurar por todas palavras no livro inteiro ou olhar o índice que está em ordem alfabética e por causa disto pode chegar rápido onde deseja, aí o índice diz em que página está a informação que deseja. Muito mais rápido, né?

Criado errado pode trazer mais malefícios que benefícios.

- [Quais as vantagens e desvantagens do uso de índices em base de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35088/101)
- [Índices desnecessários no banco são um problema?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23348/101)
- [Índices em consultas no MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32052/101)
- [O que são os índices, B-tree, hash, GiST e GIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101065/101)
- [Como aplicar indexes para melhorar a performance das queries?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55118/101)
- [Como um índice melhora a performance de uma consulta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183305/101)

> "provavelmente você não otimiza o my.cnf"

Este arquivo tem uma série de parâmetros que pode fazer o servidor de banco de dados funcionar melhor ou pior de acordo com o que precisa. Para poucos volumes fará pouca diferença. Se você não tem muita experiência mexer nisto provavelmente trará resultados ruins. Tentar explicar alguma coisa útil ficará absurdamente longa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Quanto ao `*` eu tinha visto a pergunta e as respostas, quanto ao resto da sua resposta, estou pesquisando sobre índices, vou tentar usa-lo, mas se eu usar não vou precisar usar `rand()` correto? pois preciso de um usuário por vez. a cada request

Comment: Se você quer algo aleatório, precisará, se quer garantia que não se repete tem outras maneiras de fazer isto, dependendo do volume de linhas e de quantos você precisa pegar não compensa. Só n]ao é ideal pegar desta forma. Índice não vai resolver nada aí, a não ser que índice use o `RAND()`, mas ele ainda não será útil porque a ordem será sempre a mesma se não recriar o índice todo, o que não faria sentido já que a ideia do índice é justamente não ter que ficar percorrendo toda a tabela na consulta, o que é necessário na construção.

Comment: Sim eu percebi isto agora, estou usando indice porém não ficou aleatório mesmo, tenho 1000+ registros na tabela mas a cada request nunca pode selecionar o mesmo.

Comment: @Maneiro, está retornando mais rápido agora com os índices porem, estou usando limit 1, preciso que a cada f5 dado ele me retorne outro registro diferente, nunca passando pelo mesmo id ou username, tem ideia de como proceder? `$sql = "SELECT * FROM viperusers USE INDEX (index_username) WHERE vip < 1 LIMIT 1";`