# Otimização, rapidez em select, e código PHP

Tags: php, mysql, random

[Seguindo o raciocínio desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/261121/selecionar-linhas-randomicamente), eu fiz este método, onde eu seleciono vários usuários de uma vez pra me retornar apenas 1 em ordem aleatória, ou seja, minha query que está na função faz uma varredura na tabela toda pra me retornar apenas um resultado, isso está sobrecarregando meu servidor, onde possuo mais de 2 mil contas registradas.

Aqui está meu código:

```
public function random($username) {
    if ($this->vip($username)) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `viperusers` WHERE vip < 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `viperusers` WHERE vip = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    }

    $query = $this->_db->select($sql);

    if (empty($query[0]->username)) {
        return $this->random($username);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Tá, já sei que devo usar *índices* no *mysql*, e já tenho, veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não encontro outra forma, de fazer sem usar `RAND()` no meu `SELECT`, lembrando que tenho outra tabela chamada `vipersends` que salvo o meu `ds_user_id` e o `ds_user_id` do outro usuário. Está sobrecarregando.

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode pegar n° de contas, e usar o rand() do php.

```
public function random($username) {  


    $sql = "SELECT count(idx_user) FROM `viperusers`" ;
    $query = $this->_db->select($sql);
    $total_de_contas = $query[0];
    $rr = rand(0, $total_de_contas);


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `viperusers` WHERE idx_user = $rr";

    $query = $this->_db->select($sql);

    if (empty($query[0]->username)) {
        return $this->random($username);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: E a questão da varredura na tabela toda? com isso não fará?, em relação ao index, dessa forma não funcionará, você selecionou errado desta forma me trará algum erro do tipo: Unknown column 'idx_user' in 'field list'

Comment: sim , o script apenas ira obter um  numero qualquer entre 0 e o total de contas , e logo em seguinte fazer um consulta, que ao invez de fazer uma varredura em toda a tabela , vai pegar apena um registro de acordo com o n° gerado anteriormente.

Comment: Sim eu entendi a lógica, porém o certo não seria fazer um select count(*) from tabela use index (idx_user) ?

Comment: isso funciona da mesma forma que o rand() na query msm.

Answer (score 1):

Isso pode ter vários motivos, incluindo a própria forma que organizou o banco de dados ou até mesmo o hardware. Executando um teste, em uma tabela contendo 239289977 de linhas e mais de 46GB, o `SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` demorou exatamente `00:02:07`. É um tempo grande, obviamente, mas o número de cadastros é muito maior que 2000, com essa quantidade acredito que o tempo seria *tão rápido quanto* um `SELECT` convencional.

O `RAND()` pode colaborar com a lentidão, uma vez que ele cria uma tabela temporária. As tabelas temporárias são salvas em disco (SSD/HDD) e isso vai destruir qualquer performance. *(Não sei se isso foi modificado em versões recentes do MySQL!)*. Você pode forçar o MySQL a usar a RAM, mas desde que você tenha bastante RAM, você pode usar:

```
SELECT SQL_SMALL_RESULT WHERE vip = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Isso também está limitado pelo `tmp_table_size`, configurado no my.cnf. Em geral, isso não vai mudar muito a situação.

Os indices serão ignorados na tabela temporária, isso é, o único índice que pode importar é o `vip`, somente.

---

Uma solução melhor requer que tenha dados sequenciais, todos os 2000 valores devem estar desde 0 até 1999, sem qualquer lacuna e todos eles vem ser selecionáveis (o que não é o caso).

Então bastaria fazer:

```
$maxsql = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT id FROM tabela ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');
list($max) = mysqli_fetch_row($maxsql);


$random = random_int(0, $max);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE vip = 0 AND id >= ' . random;
//...
```

Porém, no seu caso possui tanto `vip = 0` e o `vip <1`, que faz isso ser inviável, porque se torna não-uniforme. Considere que o `id=999` seja `vip=-1`, ele não poderá ser selecionado na situação acima, isso vai fazer com que o `id=1000` seja selecionado tanto com o `$random=999` quanto com o `$random=1000`.

Isso pode ser resolvido criando duas tabelas distintas, uma `tabela_normal` e outra `tabela_vip`.

---

Além disso, no final você também pode pre-computar os dados que são custosos. Se você tem `LIMIT 1`, mas executa isso muitas vezes, seria melhor gerar uma vez um `LIMIT 50` e armazenar. O custo de um `SELECT` é muito menor, no seu caso, o do que o custo do `SELECT ... RAND`, portanto ler um dado previamente gerado é muito mais rápido. Isso iria reduzir drasticamente o número de requisições. Novamente, isso está na própria arquitetura, de como construiu isso.

Comment: Bom Inkeliz, eu deixei da forma que está, o seguidores enviados fiz uma verificação pra ver se meu id e o outro id do usuário q me seguiu, não existe na tabela, acho que isso já ajuda. eu não posso fazer select por `iD` igual vc disse, sempre terá _lacunas_ e isso é inviável.

Comment: Você pode criar uma tabela especifica para isso, afinal o próprio MySQL cria lacunas (o uso de `TRANSACTION` é um exemplo).

Comment: estou vendo aqui uma maneira, eu entendi a sua resposta porém estou tentando fazer antes de fazer qualquer outra pergunta. Estou com muitas dúvidas. :/