# Otimização de modelo de banco de dados

Tags: mysql, desempenho, modelagem

Estou fazendo um sistema para uma faculdade e um dos subsistemas que estou construindo é o boletim dos alunos. Eu coloquei para quando criar uma nova disciplina na tabela "disciplina" essa disciplina é adicionada a tabela "notas" com um registro para cada id de cada aluno matriculado no curso o qual a disciplina pertence e com o campo nota nesses novos registros.

A tabela `notas` seria mais ou menos assim a estrutura dela:

```
id int(11)
iddisciplina int(11)
idcurso int(11)
idaluno int (11)
nota int(11)
```

Mas fazendo desse jeito, com uma quantidade grande de alunos isso iria gerar muitos dados e quando eu precisasse excluir um curso por exemplo, teria que sair varrendo todas as notas relacionadas a esse curso e disciplinas e isso teria um custo de desempenho grande.

Tem alguma forma melhor e mais otimizada de se fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essencialmente não, a não ser que mude o requisito. E que não tenha algum requisito não falado.

Também não acho que terá uma quantidade tão grande de dados como acha que haverá. Menos ainda que haverá problemas de desempenho, a não ser que saiba de algo que eu não sei acerca do problema.

A otimização neste caso não está na estrutura de dados e sim no algoritmo adotado, que não está na pergunta.

Obviamente que um [índice adequado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35088/101) sempre é fundamental. Se precisar apagar um curso um simples comando será executado e rapidamente executado se tiver índice do curso.

Comment: Tem alguns outros itens relacionados, como arquivos de alunos, foruns, mensagens etc... Não coloquei o código porque é muito extenso, achei melhor apenas perguntar o essencial. Eu imaginei que não teria outra maneira sem ser as relações por indices, mas perguntei para tirar essa dúvida que eu estava tendo. A primeira versão desse sistema estava demorando um pouco de mais para fazer essas operações mas creio que seja por conta de que estava em uma hospedagem compartilhada e com poucos recursos de processamento.

Comment: Eu acho que é por problema em outro lugar. Mas não tenho como saber onde sem conhecer o sistema.

Answer (score 1):

A estrutura à qual chegou corresponde à terceira forma normal, na qual informação duplicada não é permitida na base de dados.

Criar e manter bons índices é o próximo passo em termos de otimizaçÃo.

Outra coisa que você pode fazer é manter a integridade referencial removendo ou atualizando registros em cascata sempre houver a eliminação ou alteração de uma chave primária. A maioria dos bancos de dados relacionais já fazem isso automaticamente desde que você os configure propriamente.