# Impacto com a utilização de ÍNDICES no MySQL

Tags: mysql, índices

Possuo uma tabela que atualmente possui *25 milhões de registros*, devido a isto qualquer consulta que eu faça por mais simples que seja se torna muito lenta.

Estava pesquisando sobre **INDICES** para melhorar a performance nas buscas e verifiquei que auxilia muito na questão de velocidade e isso é ótimo, porém, vi diversos comentários falando sobre o impacto negativo que eles podem gerar nas inserções e alterações (deixar mais lenta).

Essa tabela que estou querendo modificar (criar indices) sofre muitas inserções e as vezes com mais de 100 mil registros por vez.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, esse impacto em **inserção** ou **alteração** após criar um índice realmente acontece?  Tenho receio de ajustar a questão das consultas, porém, atrapalhar as outras coisas

Comment: Bom sugiro subir um backup da base em outra instância, criar os índices e fazer um teste de performance. Qualquer coisa que digamos aqui vai ser especulação sem conhecer a real estrutura do banco, consultas, volume, etc... 
Um alternativa seria criar um índice por um campo data e sempre usar data para limitar as consultas, mesmo que seja carregando tabelas temporárias, isso ajuda muito na maioria dos casos, principalmente *queries* cheias de `where`, `group by` e `order by`.
Não imagino que todas as consultas façam *search* nesse 25 milhões de registros.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Quais as vantagens e desvantagens do uso de índices em base de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35088/quais-as-vantagens-e-desvantagens-do-uso-de-%c3%adndices-em-base-de-dados)