# Para que serve o índice INDEX no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, índices

Para que serve o índice `INDEX` no MySQL?

```
ALTER TABLE `tabela`
ADD INDEX `tabela_id_index` (`tabela_id` ASC);
```

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35088/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55118/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32052/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23348/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27877/101

Comment: Relacionado: [Quando e em quais colunas deve-se usar índices?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76131/18246)

Comment: Só para constar, "index" = "índice" em inglês. Parece haver uma confusão no título da questão.

Comment: @DineiRockenbach não é confusão não... É que eu diria: "índice unique" ou "índice primary"... então também me expressaria falando "índice index"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Uma maneira fácil de pensar em *indexes* é pensar num sumário de um livro, ele existe para facilitar a localização de conteúdos do livro, assim você acha um conteúdo de maneira mais fácil do que procurar página por página, *para isto depende de que os indexes sejam bem definidos*.

---

### Benefícios:

- São capazes de reduzir a quantidade de dados que o servidor teria que examinar.
- São capazes de ajudar o servidor a ordenar (ex. ORDER BY) e evitar criação de tabelas temporárias.

*O uso de "são capazes" é porque nem todo os indexes criados vão fazer isso, até porque talvez eles nunca sejam utilizados.*

---

### Tipos de Indexes:

Esses são os tipos de indexes que existem nas *engines* mais comuns:

- **B-Tree:** Mais comum de todos os tipos de indexes, basicamente com exceção do [`Archive Engine`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/archive-storage-engine.html) todos suportam ele, *porém com diferenças internas*.

  - **InnoDB  Engine** utiliza B+Tree não comprimido e são referenciados pela *Primary Key*.
  - **MyISAM Engine** utiliza B-Tree com técnicas de compreensão e são referenciados por sua localização física.
  - **NDB Cluster Engine** utiliza T-Tree.
  - **TokuDB** utiliza uma variação chamada *Fractal Tree*.

---

- **Hash:** Próprio nome já explica, ele é util apenas para diferenciação e igualdade (`IN()`, `=` e `<=>`), mas não é usado para nenhuma outra funcionalidade.

  - **MEMORY Engine** é um dos únicos que tem suporte explicito para este tipo de index.
  - **InnoDB Engine** possui *adaptative hash indexes*, quando o InnoDB identifica que alguns valores são acessados frequentemente ele criar um hash index e utiliza antes do B-Tree, porém isto é totalmente automático e não há como desligar ou criar isto.

---

- **R-Tree:** Raramente utilizado no MySQL, porém utilizado no PostgreSQL e PostGIS, ele não exige o uso do `WHERE` para se beneficiar.

  - **InnoDB Engine** é um dos único que tem suporte para este tipo de index.

---

- **Full-Text Index:** Tenha uma característica diferente e apenas usado para operações de `MATCH AGAINST`.

  - **MyISAM Engine** tem suporte para este tipo de index.
  - **InnoDB Engine** tem suporte para este tipo de index nas versões mais recentes.

*Para complementar, o ScaleDB utiliza Patricia-Tries. Já o InfiniDB e Infobright tem uma arquitetura própria (?).*

---

Como o padrão é o B-Tree, é justamente nele que irei utilizar como base para tudo aqui.

### Limitações:

- Não servem para leituras que não comecem da esquerda, por exemplo o `SELECT * FROM Tabela WHERE Nome LIKE '%A'`, para tentar achar todos nomes que terminam com `A`, porém você pode usar `A%` para achar o que comece com `A`.
- A sua query deve executar a mesma ordem os index definido, criar um `KEY(Nome, Sobrenome)` obrigatoriamente deverá informar nesta ordem. Você pode `WHERE Nome = 'Inkeliz'`, porém não poderá usar `WHERE Sobrenome = 'Lima'`. Você obrigatoriamente deve seguir a ordem, ou seja `WHERE Nome = 'Inkeliz' AND Sobrenome = 'Lima'`, por exemplo.
- Se criar um *range*, por exemplo, `WHERE Nome LIKE 'ANA%' AND Sobrenome = 'Lima'`, os indexes serão utilizados para achar a Ana, porém não será utilizado para achar os sobrenomes, isto irá ainda criar uma tabela temporária. Isso indica que você preferir deve colocar `X > 1`, `BETWEEN 1 AND 5` e `LIKE` como última condição, ou seja **todas as igualdades devem vir antes** (inclusive existem "truques"/"gambiarras" com o `IN()`), *detalho isto depois*.

### Problemas:

**Isolar colunas:**

Considere isto:

```
SELECT Nome FROM Usuarios WHERE ID + 1 = 10
```

Viu o problema? O MySQL não é capaz de fazer essa soma. Para nós, é fácil saber que `ID + 1 = 10` é o mesmo que `ID = 9`, porém o MySQL não faz isto, como consequência ele irá varrer todo o banco de dados e somar todos os ID, ignorando qualquer index.

Exemplo mais real:

```
SELECT Nome FROM Acessos WHERE TO_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE) - TO_DAYS(UltimoAcesso) <= 7
```

O mesmo problema, você irá executar o `TO_DAYS()` em tudo e depois subtrair e depois compara-lo para ver se é menor que 7. Indexes não são milagrosos nesses casos e serão ignoráveis.

**Criar *range*:**

No MySQL utilizar PODE `IN()` ser melhor do que `BETWEEN`, porém cuidado com grande número de condições, por exemplo:

```
SELECT Nome FROM Usuario WHERE Genero IN ('h', 'm') AND Idade IN (18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25) AND UltimaAcao > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Isto teria 2 * 8 possibilidades e depois seria teoricamente melhor do que:

```
SELECT Nome FROM Usuario WHERE Genero IN ('h', 'm') AND Idade BETWEEN 18 AND 25 AND UltimaAcao > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Isto ocorre porque utilizando o `BETWEEN` você geraria dois *ranges* o primeiro por `Idade` e o segundo por `UltimaAcao`, enquanto no `IN()` é igualdade. Isto ainda levanta uma outra questão, qual dos dois possui maior relevância?! Mas, porque usar `Genero IN ('h', 'm')`, **supondo que sejam as únicas opções**.

A gambiarra do `IN()` vem pela necessidade de especificar todas as colunas, por isso se fizer: `KEY(Genero, Pais, Idade)` você sempre terá que informar o Genero, Pais e Idade. Por isso usamos o `IN()`, ou seja se somente existe `h` e `m` então fazemos `Genero IN ('h', 'm')`, dessa forma "ignoramos" o `Genero` e podemos filtrar por Pais, ou fazemos um novo `IN()` com todas as listas de países e passamos para a idade. *A idade em último, novamente, porque ela tem um poder potencial de criar um *range*.

Caso usássemos:

```
SELECT Nome FROM Usuario WHERE Idade > 18 AND Genero = 'h' AND Pais = 'BR'
```

Iria obrigatoriamente ignorar os indexes de `Genero` e `Pais`, porque o primeiro, `Idade` cria um *range*.

**Relevância e ordem:**

Agora qual tem mais relevância, considere isto:

```
SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE Ativo = 0 AND id =  10;
SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE id = 10;
SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE Ativo IN (0, 1) AND id = 10;
```

O primeiro e o último poderia utilizar `KEY(Ativo, id)`, porém seria incompatível com o segundo. Porém poderíamos também fazer:

```
SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE id = 10 AND Ativo = 0;
SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE id = 10;
SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE id = 10 AND Ativo IN (0,1);
```

Assim poderíamos usar o `KEY(id, Ativo)`, todos eles iriam utilizar indexes, neste caso ele tende a ser melhor, porque o Ativo, por ser binário irá retornar mais dados do que o `id` que tende a ser único, portanto o `id` tem maior relevância e isso tem grande impacto.

Uma outra coisa é saber se não ira fazer isso:

```
SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE id > 10 AND Ativo = 0;
SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE Ativo = 0;
```

Porque se essas queries forem utilizadas o `KEY(Ativo, id)` poderia ser melhor, mas novamente depende do caso, assim usando o `Ativo IN()` antes mesmo que somente fosse selecionar o `id`.

Um outro problema é criar vários indexes separados por cada coluna, isto é terrível e raramente são úteis.

**Colunas separadas:**

Criar indexes separados podem ser bons caso utilize:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE Nome = 'Inkeliz' OR Idade = 18
```

Caso crie indexes separados, `Nome` e `Idade` o MySQL fará um UNION dos dois resultados, usando cada index separado. No entanto fazer isto:

```
 SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE Nome = 'Inkeliz' AND Idade = 18
```

Não irá se beneficiar de ambos dos indexes, ele apenas irá optar por utilizar um deles, não os dois. *Na maioria das vezes criar indexes dividos não é bom*, em resumo.

O `ORDER BY` e `GROUP BY` também se beneficia dos indexes, porém desde que não crie um *range*, porque neste caso cai num *filesort* mesmo, não tem jeito, *exceto fazer um RAID-0 de SSD*.

---

Indexes são complexos, tem dois livros sobre isto, infelizmente não cobrem o MySQL 5.6 e MySQL 5.7, [e aparentemente não há nova versão para ser lançada](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2012/04/01/progress-on-high-performance-mysql-4th-edition/), são eles:

[High Performance MySQL: Optimization, Backups, and Replication](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449314287), tem uma versão traduzida pela Altas Books (mas é mais antigo ainda e existe várias reclamações de falhas na tradução), nele que menciona o uso da gambiarra do `IN()`, não é minha autoria (e deu uma boa reduzida de RAM, *deletando indexes repetidos*).

[Relational Database Index Design and the Optimizers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011DBKM0C), praticamente um livro somente somente *indexes*, *este ainda está na fila para ser lido*, o livro acima indica este também. :)

Answer (score 14):

Para se criar um `índice` (Os índices são utilizados para encontrar registros com um valor específico de uma coluna rapidamente. Sem um índice o MySQL tem de iniciar com o primeiro registro e depois ler através de toda a tabela até que ele encontre os registros relevantes)

Citação da Locaweb

> Um dos itens mais importantes na otimização da base de dados é a
>   criação de índices. Com este procedimento sua consulta ficará bem mais
>   rápida. O ideal é que crie índices em todos os campos utilizados nas
>   cláusulas "where" e "joins" de suas queries.

Esta resposta do SOen da uma demonstração de como se criar um índice: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002605/how-to-add-indexes-to-mysql-tables)

Comparação entre `CREATE INDEX` e `ALTER TABLE`tabela`ADD INDEX`: [Link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46623/create-index-vs-alter-table-add-index-mysqlism-or-sql-standard)

`Index` documentação Mysql: [Link](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/4.1/pt/mysql-indexes.html)

Answer (score 4):

Índices são estruturas de acesso auxiliares associadas às tabelas e que têm por objetivo aumentar o desempenho na execução de consultas.

existem dois tipos de index:
Clusterizado: esse ordenado sequencialmente.

Não Clusterizado:

Um índice cuja chave de busca especifica uma ordem diferente da ordem sequencial do arquivo.