# Trazer registros que não está em outra tabela

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

```
SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE status='publicado' AND NOT quiz.id_quiz IN (SELECT id_quiz FROM quiz_resolvido WHERE quiz_resolvido.id_usuario=1) order by rand() LIMIT 0,10;
```

Hoje uso essa Query para selecionar somente os quizes que não foram resolvidos pelo usuario selecionado 1.

Tem ficado muito lento por conta de muitas linhas na tabela quiz_resolvidos. Tem uma forma melhor de exibir os quizes que não foram resolvidos pelo usuário selecionado 1?

Comment: Exponha a estrutura das suas tabelas (inclusive com as chaves) para avaliarmos como o banco de dados está realizando a consulta

Comment: Leia [isso](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization.html)

Comment: Nesse caso tu fica com poucas opções, o que tu pode fazer é criar uma mv para a tabela quiz_resolvido, assim poderá ficar mais rápido.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crie um índice para a sua tabela:

```
ALTER TABLE quiz_resolvido ADD INDEX quiz_resolvido_index (id_usuario, id_quiz);
```

Mais informações na resposta da pergunta [**Índices em consultas no MySQL**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32072/59479) e [**Para que serve o índice INDEX no MySQL?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193305/59479).

A resposta do [Alex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/140345/alex) com relação ao `NOT EXISTS` também deve melhorar um pouco a performance, só que, talvez, não seja o suficiente.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT *
    FROM quiz a
   WHERE status = 'publicado'
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM quiz_resolvido b
                      WHERE a.id_quiz = b.id_quiz
                        AND b.id_usuario = 1)
```

Comment: Ainda muito lento. São mais de 4 milhões de registros em resolvidos.