# SELECT COUNT com baixa performance no mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query

Faço uso de uma query dentro do PHP para exibir a lista de categorias e subcategorias relacionadas, tenho de retorno mais de 10 mil resultados (está certo) em 3 segundos em média, mas depois que implementei uma subquery para verificar a quantidade de subcategorias relacionadas, a consulta oscilou entre 15-17 segundos.

Sem SUBQUERY (3s em média):

```
$sql_query = "SELECT t.* FROM `table` t 
WHERE 
    t.`tbl_id` = '".mysqli_fetch_array($dbconn,$id)."' 
ORDER BY 
    (CASE WHEN t.`tbl_nome` = 'Outros' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASC, 
t.`tbl_nome` ASC;
```

Com SUBQUERY (15> em média):

```
$sql_query = "SELECT t.*,
(SELECT COUNT(n.`tbl_id`) FROM `categoria` n WHERE n.`tbl_pai` = t.`tbl_id` LIMIT 1) 
AS `numSubs` 
FROM 
    `table` t 
WHERE 
    t.`tbl_id` = '".mysqli_fetch_array($dbconn,$id)."' 
ORDER BY 
    (CASE WHEN t.`tbl_nome` = 'Outros' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASC, 
t.`tbl_nome` ASC;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Adicionei o COUNT para verificar se outros registros no campo `tbl_pai` tem o ID diferente de NULL e se é o ID da categoria a ser consultada.

**DÚVIDA**:

Existe outro meio para verificar se outros campos possuem ID da categoria atual no campo `tbl_pai` que seja 1 apenas, que tem o campo pai com o ID da categoria atual. ? Assim otimizar a query e parar com a lentidão?

Comment: Certo, e qual é a dúvida? :)

Comment: Consegue postar a estrutura da tabela?

Comment: Consegui, anexei na pergunta =)

Comment: O pior é que a query está dentro de um looping, e não poderia ser feito diferente para os fins solicitado.

Comment: Qual o problema da negativação da pergunta? Ao menos nem justificam o porque disso.

Comment: Possivelmente negativaram antes de você editar.

Comment: Fica muito mais fácil se você postar o que tem dentro das tabelas (pelo menos como um exemplo) e o que você deseja obter. Fica bem complicado dar uma resposta sem ter como testar ou tendo que inventar dados pra testar

Comment: @Sorack é que são dados sensíveis, mas tem uns 10k+ e a estrutura é essa apenas, os dados relacionados estão em outras tabelas mas não são utilizados nessa parte do código.

Comment: @EliseuB. Se você não faz questão nem de colocar dados de exemplo, que não precisam ser os reais mas só que demonstrem seu problema eu não vou fazer questão de tentar responder também. O mínimo seria você facilitar o que você pode pra quem quer tentar te ajudar.

Comment: @Sorack o problema está na query, que caiu a performance ao executá-la, não precisa de dados, não se trata de dados, é mais uma otimização dela (query) ou outro modo de relacionamento, deixei bem explicado o que está havendo. Obrigado!

Comment: @EliseuB. e como alguém pode sugerir uma melhoria da `query` garantindo que os dados não serão alterados?

Comment: vc precisa usar o EXPLAIN e postar o resultado, so assim da para saber aonde esta o problema de perfomance

Comment: @Sorack os dados não serão alterados, são dados permanentes, fiz a melhoria sugerida e depois fiz um sistema de cache do DB em HTML estático, o que muda é a tabela de produtos, mas está boa a performance por lá, essa não preciso me preocupar, e a sugestão do INDEX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua `query` possui inconsistências (como o `LIMIT` no `COUNT`), porém sem dados para uma resposta mais elaborada só posso sugerir o seguinte:

Crie um índice para a sua tabela:

```
ALTER TABLE categoria ADD INDEX categoria_index (tbl_pai);
```

Mais informações na resposta da pergunta [**Índices em consultas no MySQL**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32072/59479) e [**Para que serve o índice INDEX no MySQL?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193305/59479).

Comment: Eu leio várias perguntas sobre performance em BD e percebi que as pessoas hoje não fazem o mas simples que é criar índices, fazer um diagnóstico de performance ou criar um plano de execução. +1

Comment: @AugustoVasques pois é, eu queria que na pergunta houvessem dados para que eu pudesse consultar o plano de execução, mas como isso não foi informado acho que só o índice deve melhorar em algo

Comment: Melhorou e muito, @Sorack desculpe por aparentar não dar importância para a minha pergunta, arrisquei sabendo que no mínimo devo estruturar uma boa pergunta para obter ajuda, mas além dos dados que passei seria arriscado, e inserir perguntas no celular é horrível, obrigado pela paciência.

Comment: @Sorack caraca, está mais rápido que antes de inserir o COUNT =D

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar outras estratégias, como por exemplo, construir uma View sumarizando o número de subitens por tbl_pai:

```
Select tbl_pai, count(*) as qtde from categoria Group by tbl_pai
```

Assim, sempre que quiser, poderá fazer um join com esta view.

No modelo que está utilizando, com 10 mil categorias, ele fará muito processamento item a item, acho que pode tentar um código similar ao código abaixo que calcula a quantidade de itens por categoria pai de uma só vez e depois faz o join com esse resultado. (verifique o código, estou sem ambiente para testar, mas seria algo como abaixo)

```
SELECT 
    t.campo1, t.campo2, t.campo3..., sum(n.qtde) as numSubs  --- como será um agrupamento. adicionar todos 
                                                             --- os campos necessário e depois adicionar no group by
From
    table t

    -- assumindo que todos os itens tem um filho pelo menos
    inner join (
        select  categoria.tbl_pai, 
                count(*) as qtde
        from    
                categoria 
        group by 
                tbl_pai) as n 

                on n.tbl_pai = t.tbl_id

WHERE 
    t.tbl_id = '<<condicao>>' 

GROUP BY 
    t.campo1, t.campo2, t.campo3, t.campo4.... -- adicionar todos os campos necessários

ORDER BY 
        (CASE WHEN t.tbl_nome = 'Outros' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASC, 
        t.tbl_nome ASC;
```

Lembre-se de enumerar todos os campos da 'table' que você quer mostrar tanto no início do select, quanto no group by.

Comment: Amanhã cedo farei o teste, obrigado por enquanto, assim que realizado posto como que ficou se deu certo ou não com a performance, obrigado desde já!