# Eu um select aonde o mesmo esta começando a fica lento demais, Teria alguma solução para melhorar sua velociadade?

Tags: mysql, sql

```html
SELECT 
  pessoafisica.PessoaFisica_Nome,
  filiados.`Filiado_MatriculaEmpresa`,
  filiados.`Filiado_RetornoSiape` AS observacoes,
  Filiado_MatriculaEmpresaDigito,
 lotacao.Lotacao_Descricao,
  (SELECT 
    contato.Contato_Valor 
  FROM
    filiadoshascontato,
    contato 
  WHERE filiadoshascontato.FiliadosHasContato_Filiados_Id = filiados.Filiado_Id 
    AND filiadoshascontato.FiliadosHasContato_Contato_Id = contato.Contato_Id 
    AND Contato_TipoContato_Id = 10 
  LIMIT 1) AS Telefone_Residencial,
  (SELECT 
    contato.Contato_Valor 
  FROM
    filiadoshascontato,
    contato 
  WHERE filiadoshascontato.FiliadosHasContato_Filiados_Id = filiados.Filiado_Id 
    AND filiadoshascontato.FiliadosHasContato_Contato_Id = contato.Contato_Id 
    AND Contato_TipoContato_Id = 11 
  LIMIT 1) AS Telefone_Celular,
  (SELECT 
    contato.Contato_Valor 
  FROM
    filiadoshascontato,
    contato 
  WHERE filiadoshascontato.FiliadosHasContato_Filiados_Id = filiados.Filiado_Id 
    AND filiadoshascontato.FiliadosHasContato_Contato_Id = contato.Contato_Id 
    AND Contato_TipoContato_Id = 9 
  LIMIT 1) AS Telefone_Comercial,
  (SELECT 
    contato.Contato_Valor 
  FROM
    filiadoshascontato,
    contato 
  WHERE filiadoshascontato.FiliadosHasContato_Filiados_Id = filiados.Filiado_Id 
    AND filiadoshascontato.FiliadosHasContato_Contato_Id = contato.Contato_Id 
    AND Contato_TipoContato_Id = 3 
  LIMIT 1) AS Fax,
  (SELECT 
    contato.Contato_Valor 
  FROM
    filiadoshascontato,
    contato 
  WHERE filiadoshascontato.FiliadosHasContato_Filiados_Id = filiados.Filiado_Id 
    AND filiadoshascontato.FiliadosHasContato_Contato_Id = contato.Contato_Id 
    AND Contato_TipoContato_Id = 4 
  LIMIT 1) AS Email_Principal,
  (SELECT 
    contato.Contato_Valor 
  FROM
    filiadoshascontato,
    contato 
  WHERE filiadoshascontato.FiliadosHasContato_Filiados_Id = filiados.Filiado_Id 
    AND filiadoshascontato.FiliadosHasContato_Contato_Id = contato.Contato_Id 
    AND Contato_TipoContato_Id = 5 
  LIMIT 1) AS Email_Secundario,
  (SELECT 
    contato.Contato_Valor 
  FROM
    filiadoshascontato,
    contato 
  WHERE filiadoshascontato.FiliadosHasContato_Filiados_Id = filiados.Filiado_Id 
    AND filiadoshascontato.FiliadosHasContato_Contato_Id = contato.Contato_Id 
    AND Contato_TipoContato_Id = 6 
  LIMIT 1) AS Email_Terciario,
  (SELECT 
    contato.Contato_Valor 
  FROM
    filiadoshascontato,
    contato 
  WHERE filiadoshascontato.FiliadosHasContato_Filiados_Id = filiados.Filiado_Id 
    AND filiadoshascontato.FiliadosHasContato_Contato_Id = contato.Contato_Id 
    AND Contato_TipoContato_Id = 8 
  LIMIT 1) AS Home_Page,
  (SELECT 
    filiadosiape.`FiliadoSiape_DataInicioPensao` 
  FROM
    filiadosiape 
  WHERE filiadosiape.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` = filiados.Filiado_Id 
  LIMIT 1) AS Data_Pensao,
  (SELECT 
    funcaoempresa.`FuncaoEmpresa_Valor` 
  FROM
    funcaoempresa 
    WHERE funcaoempresa.`FuncaoEmpresa_Id` = `lotacaofiliado`.`FuncaoEmpresa_Id`
    AND lotacaofiliado.`Filiados_Filiado_Id`    
  LIMIT 1) AS Funcao,
  (SELECT 
    profissao.`Profissao_Valor` 
  FROM
    profissao 
  WHERE profissao.`Profissao_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id_Profissao_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS Profissao,
   (SELECT 
    lotacao.`Lotacao_Descricao`
  FROM
    lotacao 
    WHERE lotacao.`Lotacao_Id` = lotacaofiliado.`Lotacao_Id` 
    AND lotacaofiliado.`Filiados_Filiado_Id`    
  LIMIT 1) AS Lotacao,
  (SELECT 
    cargoempresa.`CargoEmpresa_Valor` 
  FROM
    cargoempresa 
    WHERE cargoempresa.`CargoEmpresa_Id` = lotacaofiliado.`CargoEmpresa_Id`
    AND lotacaofiliado.`Filiados_Filiado_Id`
  LIMIT 1) AS Cargo,
 (SELECT 
    situacaoenviosiape.`SituacaoEnvioSiape_Valor` 
  FROM
    situacaoenviosiape
    WHERE `situacaoenviosiape`.`SituacaoEnvioSiape_Id` = `filiadosiape`.`SituacaoEnvioSiape_SituacaoEnvioSiape_Id`
    AND filiadosiape.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS Situacao_Envio,
  (SELECT 
    sexo.`Sexo_Valor` 
  FROM
    pessoafisica 
    WHERE sexo.`Sexo_Id` = pessoafisica.`PessoaFisica_Sexo_Id`
  LIMIT 1) AS Sexo,
  (SELECT 
    endereco.`Endereco_Rua` 
  FROM
    endereco 
  WHERE endereco.`Endereco_Id` = pessoafisica.PessoaFisica_Endereco_Id 
  LIMIT 1) AS Endereco,
  (SELECT 
    predio.`Predio_Descricao` 
  FROM
    filiadoshasempresa 
  WHERE predio.`Predio_Empresa_Id` = fhe.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS Predio,
  (SELECT 
    empresa.`Empresa_Codigo` 
  FROM
    empresa 
  WHERE empresa.`Empresa_Id` = fhe.`Empresa_Empresa_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS Empresa_Codigo,
  (SELECT 
    empresa.`Empresa_Nome` 
  FROM
    empresa 
  WHERE empresa.`Empresa_Id` = fhe.`Empresa_Empresa_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS Empresa_Nome,
  (SELECT 
    IF (
      filiados.Filiado_Filiado = 0,
      'Não',
      'Sim'
    ) 
  LIMIT 1) AS Associado,
  (SELECT 
    IF (
      dadosfinanceirosfiliado.`DadosFinanceirosFiliado_Valor` IS NULL,
      0,
      1
    ) 
  FROM
    dadosfinanceirosfiliado 
  WHERE CONCAT(
      dadosfinanceirosfiliado.`DadosFinanceirosFiliado_CompetenciaAno`,
      dadosfinanceirosfiliado.`DadosFinanceirosFiliado_CompetenciaMes`
    ) = CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), MONTH(NOW()) - 1) 
    AND dadosfinanceirosfiliado.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS Desconto,
  (SELECT 
    estadocivil.`EstadoCivil_Valor` 
  FROM
    pessoafisica 
  WHERE estadocivil.`EstadoCivil_Id` = pessoafisica.`PessoaFisica_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS Est_Civil,
  (SELECT 
    fatorrh.`FatorRh_Valor` 
  FROM
    pessoafisica 
  WHERE fatorrh.`FatorRh_Id` = pessoafisica.`PessoaFisica_FatorRh_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS Fator_Rh,
  (SELECT 
    pessoafisica.`PessoaFisica_DataNascimento` 
  FROM
    pessoafisica 
  WHERE pessoafisica.`PessoaFisica_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS Data_Nascimento,
  (SELECT 
    grauinstrucao.`GrauInstrucao_Valor` 
  FROM
    pessoafisica 
  WHERE grauinstrucao.`GrauInstrucao_Id` = pessoafisica.`PessoaFisica_GrauInstrucao_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS Grau_Istrucao,
  (SELECT 
    pessoafisica.`PessoaFisica_NomePai` 
  FROM
    pessoafisica 
  WHERE pessoafisica.`PessoaFisica_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS Pai,
  (SELECT 
    pessoafisica.`PessoaFisica_NomeMae` 
  FROM
    pessoafisica 
  WHERE pessoafisica.`PessoaFisica_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS Mae,
  (SELECT 
    raca.`Raca_Valor` 
  FROM
    pessoafisica 
  WHERE raca.`Raca_Id` = pessoafisica.`PessoaFisica_Raca_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS Raca,
  (SELECT 
    situacaoempresa.`SituacaoEmpresa_Valor` 
  FROM
    situacaoempresa 
  WHERE situacaoempresa.`SituacaoEmpresa_Id` = dadosempresa.`SituacaoEmpresa_SituacaoEmpresa_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS Situacao_Empresa,
  (SELECT 
    vinculoempregaticio.`VinculoEmpregaticio_Valor` 
  FROM
    vinculoempregaticio 
  WHERE vinculoempregaticio.`VinculoEmpregaticio_Id` = dadosempresa.`VinculoEmpregaticio_VinculoEmpregaticio_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) Vinculo,
  (SELECT 
    dadossindicato.`DadosSindicato_DataFiliacao` 
  FROM
    dadossindicato 
  WHERE dadossindicato.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS Data_Filiacao,
  (SELECT 
    filiacaodesfiliacao.`FiliacaoDesfiliacao_Data` 
  FROM
    filiacaodesfiliacao 
  WHERE filiacaodesfiliacao.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id` LIMIT 1) AS Data_Desfiliacao,
  (SELECT 
    urna.`Urna_Urna` 
  FROM
    urna 
  WHERE urna.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id` LIMIT 1) AS Urna,
  (SELECT 
    urna.`Urna_UltimaVotacao` 
  FROM
    urna 
  WHERE urna.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id` LIMIT 1) AS Urna_Votacao,
  (SELECT 
    dadossindicatocarteirinha.`Carteirinha_Emissao` 
  FROM
    dadossindicatocarteirinha 
  WHERE dadossindicatocarteirinha.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id` LIMIT 1) AS Carteira_Emissao,
  (SELECT 
    dadossindicatocarteirinha.`Carteirinha_Validade` 
  FROM
    dadossindicatocarteirinha 
  WHERE dadossindicatocarteirinha.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id` LIMIT 1) AS Carteira_Validade,
   (SELECT 
    cipa.`Cipa_Membro` 
  FROM
    cipa 
  WHERE cipa.`Cipa_Id` = cipahasfiliados.`Cipa_Cipa_Id` 
  AND cipahasfiliados.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id`
  LIMIT 1) AS Membro_Cipa,
  (SELECT 
    cipa.`Cipa_Eleito` 
  FROM
    cipa 
  WHERE cipa.`Cipa_Id` = cipahasfiliados.`Cipa_Cipa_Id` 
    AND cipahasfiliados.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id`
  LIMIT 1) AS Eleito,
  (SELECT 
    cipa.`Cipa_Mandato` 
  FROM
    cipa 
  WHERE cipa.`Cipa_Id` = cipahasfiliados.`Cipa_Cipa_Id` 
    AND cipahasfiliados.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id`
  LIMIT 1) AS Mandato,
  (SELECT 
    cipa.`Cipa_FimMandato` 
  FROM
    cipa 
  WHERE cipa.`Cipa_Id` = cipahasfiliados.`Cipa_Cipa_Id` 
    AND cipahasfiliados.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id`
  LIMIT 1) AS Fim_Mandato,
  (SELECT 
    documento.`Documento_Valor` 
  FROM
    documento 
    INNER JOIN filiadoshasdocumento fhd 
      ON fhd.`Documento_Documento_Id` = documento.`Documento_Id` 
  WHERE documento.`Documento_TipoDocumento_Id` = 7 
    AND filiados.Filiado_Id = fhd.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS Identidade,
  (SELECT 
    documento.`Documento_Valor` 
  FROM
    documento 
    INNER JOIN filiadoshasdocumento fhd 
      ON fhd.`Documento_Documento_Id` = documento.`Documento_Id` 
  WHERE documento.`Documento_TipoDocumento_Id` = 6 
    AND filiados.Filiado_Id = fhd.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS CPF,
  (SELECT 
    documento.`Documento_Valor` 
  FROM
    documento 
    INNER JOIN filiadoshasdocumento fhd 
      ON fhd.`Documento_Documento_Id` = documento.`Documento_Id` 
  WHERE documento.`Documento_TipoDocumento_Id` = 8 
    AND filiados.Filiado_Id = fhd.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS Ctps,
  (SELECT 
    documento.`Documento_Valor` 
  FROM
    documento 
    INNER JOIN filiadoshasdocumento fhd 
      ON fhd.`Documento_Documento_Id` = documento.`Documento_Id` 
  WHERE documento.`Documento_TipoDocumento_Id` = 9 
    AND filiados.Filiado_Id = fhd.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS PIS,
  (SELECT 
    documento.`Documento_Valor` 
  FROM
    documento 
    INNER JOIN filiadoshasdocumento fhd 
      ON fhd.`Documento_Documento_Id` = documento.`Documento_Id` 
  WHERE documento.`Documento_TipoDocumento_Id` = 13 
    AND filiados.Filiado_Id = fhd.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS FGTS,
  (SELECT 
    documento.`Documento_Valor` 
  FROM
    documento 
    INNER JOIN filiadoshasdocumento fhd 
      ON fhd.`Documento_Documento_Id` = documento.`Documento_Id` 
  WHERE documento.`Documento_TipoDocumento_Id` = 13 
    AND filiados.Filiado_Id = fhd.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS Data_FGTS
FROM
  filiados 
  INNER JOIN pessoafisica pessoafisica 
    ON filiados.Filiado_PessoaFisica_Id = pessoafisica.PessoaFisica_Id 
  INNER JOIN filiadoshasempresa fhe 
    ON filiados.Filiado_Id = fhe.Filiados_Filiado_Id 
  INNER JOIN empresa 
    ON fhe.Empresa_Empresa_Id = empresa.Empresa_Id 
  LEFT JOIN endereco 
    ON endereco.Endereco_Id = pessoafisica.PessoaFisica_Endereco_Id 
  LEFT JOIN cidadeestado 
    ON endereco.Endereco_CidadeEstado_Id = cidadeestado.CidadeEstado_Id 
  LEFT JOIN lotacaofiliado 
   ON lotacaofiliado.Filiados_Filiado_Id = filiados.Filiado_Id 
  LEFT JOIN predio p 
    ON p.Predio_Id = lotacaofiliado.Predio_Id 
  LEFT JOIN endereco AS enderedoPredio 
    ON enderedoPredio.Endereco_Id = p.Predio_Endereco_Id 
  LEFT JOIN dadosempresa de 
    ON de.Filiados_Filiado_Id = filiados.Filiado_Id 
  LEFT JOIN filiadosiape 
    ON filiadosiape.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` = filiados.Filiado_Id 
  LEFT JOIN funcaoempresa 
    ON lotacaofiliado.`FuncaoEmpresa_Id` = funcaoempresa.`FuncaoEmpresa_Id` 
  LEFT JOIN cargoempresa 
    ON lotacaofiliado.`CargoEmpresa_Id` = cargoempresa.`CargoEmpresa_Id`   
  LEFT JOIN situacaoenviosiape 
    ON filiadosiape.`FiliadoSiape_Id` = situacaoenviosiape.`SituacaoEnvioSiape_Id` 
  LEFT JOIN lotacao
    ON lotacaofiliado.`Lotacao_Id` = lotacao.`Lotacao_Id`
  LEFT JOIN sexo 
    ON pessoafisica.`PessoaFisica_Sexo_Id` = sexo.`Sexo_Id` 
  LEFT JOIN predio 
    ON predio.`Predio_Empresa_Id` = filiados.Filiado_Id 
  LEFT JOIN estadocivil 
    ON estadocivil.`EstadoCivil_Id` = pessoafisica.`PessoaFisica_EstadoCivil_Id` 
  LEFT JOIN fatorrh 
    ON fatorrh.`FatorRh_Id` = pessoafisica.`PessoaFisica_FatorRh_Id` 
  LEFT JOIN grauinstrucao 
    ON grauinstrucao.`GrauInstrucao_Id` = pessoafisica.`PessoaFisica_GrauInstrucao_Id` 
  LEFT JOIN raca 
    ON raca.`Raca_Id` = pessoafisica.`PessoaFisica_Raca_Id` 
  LEFT JOIN dadosempresa 
    ON dadosempresa.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id` 
  LEFT JOIN vinculoempregaticio 
    ON vinculoempregaticio.`VinculoEmpregaticio_Id` = dadosempresa.`VinculoEmpregaticio_VinculoEmpregaticio_Id` 
  LEFT JOIN dadossindicato 
    ON dadossindicato.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id` 
  LEFT JOIN filiacaodesfiliacao 
    ON filiacaodesfiliacao.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id` 
  LEFT JOIN urna 
    ON urna.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id` 
  LEFT JOIN dadossindicatocarteirinha 
    ON dadossindicatocarteirinha.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id` 
  LEFT JOIN cipahasfiliados 
    ON cipahasfiliados.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id`
```

Comment: talvez para o seu caso seja interessante trabalhar com INDEX, mas eu digo TALVEZ, confere esta publicação, veja os porquês e os por ondes, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73654/para-que-serve-o-%C3%ADndice-index-no-mysql

Comment: Eu não acho que INDEX irá solucionar o problema, até porque nem todos os WHERE podem usar INDEX, como no `CONCAT(dadosfinanceirosfiliado....) = CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), MONTH(NOW()) - 1)`. Primeiro, veja no EXPLAIN/PROFILE o que está lento, no meu chute vai ser o estágio de "Preparing". Se for "Preparing" a razão seria a quantidade de subquery que existe. Sem contar que há SELECTs de coisas que já estão no `INNER JOIN`. Eu estaria surpreso se essa query estivesse rápida, porque por mim ela tem tudo para ser lenta.

Comment: Oq vc aconselharia a fazer ???

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que você faz uma quantidade enorme e desnecessária de subselects.
Pelo menos aqui:

```
  (SELECT 
     empresa.`Empresa_Codigo` 
  FROM
     empresa 
  WHERE empresa.`Empresa_Id` = fhe.`Empresa_Empresa_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS Empresa_Codigo,
  (SELECT 
     empresa.`Empresa_Nome` 
  FROM
     empresa 
  WHERE empresa.`Empresa_Id` = fhe.`Empresa_Empresa_Id` 
  LIMIT 1) AS Empresa_Nome,
```

e também aqui:

```
 (SELECT 
     dadossindicatocarteirinha.`Carteirinha_Emissao` 
  FROM
     dadossindicatocarteirinha 
  WHERE dadossindicatocarteirinha.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id` LIMIT 1) AS Carteira_Emissao,
  (SELECT 
     dadossindicatocarteirinha.`Carteirinha_Validade` 
  FROM
     dadossindicatocarteirinha 
  WHERE dadossindicatocarteirinha.`Filiados_Filiado_Id` = filiados.`Filiado_Id` LIMIT 1) AS Carteira_Validade,
```

você faz 2 subselects na mesma tabela para pegar dois campos que estão relacionados.

Aparentemente sua query não saiu completa e sim, ela pode ser bastante otimizada.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem muitas ligações de tabela usando o  **LEFT JOIN** tenta criar um ídice pra cada tabela e faz a união somente dos ID's.

> CREATE  INDEX [nome_do_indice] ON nome_da_tabela ON
>   [PRIMARY]

em quase tudo tem esse  trecho:

> SELECT 
>       contato.Contato_Valor    FROM
>       filiadoshascontato,
>       contato    WHERE filiadoshascontato.FiliadosHasContato_Filiados_Id = filiados.Filiado_Id 
>       AND filiadoshascontato.FiliadosHasContato_Contato_Id = contato.Contato_Id 
>       AND Contato_TipoContato_Id = 8

Você modificando o **AND Contato_TipoContato_Id = 8** poderia fazer isso como uma tabela do from.
EX:

> SELECT 
>       DECODE(Contato_TipoContato_Id ,10, contato.Contato_Valor ) AS Telefone_Residencial ,   FROM
>       filiadoshascontato,
>       contato    WHERE filiadoshascontato.FiliadosHasContato_Filiados_Id = filiados.Filiado_Id 
>       AND filiadoshascontato.FiliadosHasContato_Contato_Id = contato.Contato_Id  DECODE(Contato_TipoContato_Id ,11,
>   contato.Contato_Valor ) AS Telefone_Celular

Comment: Já esta com index, e mesmo assim ta ficando lento

Comment: O problema é o excesso de subselect, começaria mudando esse monte de select no selec principal.Modifiquei a resposta, dê uma olhada.